# Configure downloadable product dependent on virtual product(subscription) in magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, downloadable, virtual-products

I am creating magento store which provides `downloadable products` like PDF's which depends on **subscriptions** `(virtual product)`

(Just like Shutterstock)

These downloadable products are not buy able **individually**.

```
If customer buys subscription then only he can download the products.
```

How to configure it properly ?

Right now i have done it very complexly is there any simple approach.

Thanks.

**Update1**
Right now i have created a table in which consists the data regarding customer's subscriptions like subscription start and end date and the number of downloads.

On product download action it validates customer's subscription for downloading the product.

**Update2 (Current Workaround)**
I have created a separate table which has some entries on customer buy subscription. And on each download action, this table is checked the customer has bought the subscription or not.

Comment: Which approach you tried ?

Comment: @AdityaShah I have updated my question, please let me know if you got something better.

Comment: Okay :) i will try my best

Comment: What do you wanna sell i mean like eBooks, software applications, music, updates, games.. so we can decide config approach

Comment: It is all the digital stuff right now eBooks, music, videos and other things are in pipeline.

Comment: Knight, Have you tried cart price rules ?

Comment: it will fulfill your requirement.

Comment: Actually, there are almost 100K + virtual products and all those are not individually buyable. So that cart price rule may be a more costly approach. What do you think?

Comment: Ohh that's huge !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83778/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-knight017).